# How can I bind this Icon's Color to this Label Color?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin.forms.shell

As you can see below, the `FlyoutItem` has an Icon and a `Title`.

```xml
    <FlyoutItem Title="About" >
        <FlyoutItem.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIconFont"
                            Glyph="{StaticResource InformationOutlineGlyph}"
                            Color="Green" />
        </FlyoutItem.Icon>

        <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
```

The `Title` Color changes automatically because of this `Style`:

```xml
<Style Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                        <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So the `Label` that is the `Title` changes color automatically when the `FlyoutItem` is selected.  I need the `Icon` to do the same thing. I *could* use a trigger to set the `FontImageSource` but that comes with its own problems.

Given the `TargetName` "FlyoutItemLabel" from the above `Style`, is it possible to create a binding from the `FontImageSource.Color` to each `FlyoutItem`'s `"FlyoutItemLabel".Color`?  It would have to bind upward to the `FlyoutItem` ancestor, then downward to the `<Label x:Name="FlyoutItemLabel" />`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `[ItemTemplate][1]` of **FlyoutItem** as you want

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource FloutItemStyle}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding xxx}"
        Margin="5"
        BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference label} ,Path=BackgroundColor}"
        HeightRequest="45" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       x:Name="label"
                       BackgroundColor="Red"
        Text="{Binding Title}"
        FontAttributes="Italic"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm don't understand where this code would go so it can be reused.  Would it be in a `Style` targeting the `FlyoutItem` type?

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#define-flyoutitem-appearance